# Is there any way i can limit this for loop to a maximum of 50 loops?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

This is a really unusual code i haven't written myself, each day a database is updated with around 200 records.
This means we have to do 200 api calls to figure out infomation about theese records every day at 7 am.
This has been working fine until now,
the api has implemented a limit of 50 api calls pr hour, and IF you try to do 51 calls, you get banned for 24 hours...

SO, how do i make the for loop do a maximum of 50 loops here?

```
for (let record of records ) {
    //This loop has to be limited to 50 iterations pr run.
    let brregRawData = await fetch(`some url/${record.name}/someurl`);
    let brregJson = await brregRawData.json()
    let personNavn = brregJson.rollegrupper[0].roller[0].person.navn.fornavn
    let personEtternavn = brregJson.rollegrupper[0].roller[0].person.navn.etternavn
    // if mellomnavn = undefined, then do nothing
    if (brregJson.rollegrupper[0].roller[0].person.navn.mellomnavn == undefined) { 
        var personMellomNavn = ""
    } else {
        let personMellomNavn = brregJson.rollegrupper[0].roller[0].person.navn.mellomnavn + " "
    }
```

I tried looking up different ways to use a for loop, but all the solutions i looked at broke the "${record.name}" part of the url, i have to loop through an entire view of an entire database.

Comment: [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) the records array

Comment: Maybe ask api provider, did they provide any api call can pass record id list (your update record id) and return all at once ? bulk query api ?

Comment: Yeah this was my first idea, but the API provider is none other than the Norwegian Government. Tried to call the API department but there's no one answering the phones or answering emails.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I'm familiar with the .slice function, but i haven't found a way to correctly apply it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple way to do this is implementing a `count` that increments every time the loop executes the body. So for the the loop you provided it would look like this:

```
let count = 0; // initialize count as 0

for (let record of records ) {

    if(count >= 50) break; // break out of loop if count is equal to or greater than 50 (since count starts from 0)

    //This loop has to be limited to 50 iterations pr run.
    let brregRawData = await fetch(`some_url/${record.name}/some_url`);
    let brregJson = await brregRawData.json()
    let personNavn = brregJson.rollegrupper[0].roller[0].person.navn.fornavn
    let personEtternavn = brregJson.rollegrupper[0].roller[0].person.navn.etternavn
    
    // if mellomnavn = undefined, then do nothing
    if (brregJson.rollegrupper[0].roller[0].person.navn.mellomnavn == undefined) { 
        var personMellomNavn = ""
    } else {
        let personMellomNavn = brregJson.rollegrupper[0].roller[0].person.navn.mellomnavn + " "
    }

    count++; // Increment the count after each iteration
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution, tested this one and it works perfectly for my intention!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is right for the case, but can you define a counter outside of the loop, increment internally and break when it reaches 50.

```
let count = 0;
for (....)
   ...
   if (count++ > 50) break;
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i wanted to do, and it works!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you need to limit the number of api calls to 50 but the current implementation uses a `for ... of` loop. The simplest way to achieve what you're looking for with the least amount of modification is to use a standard `for` loop.

Assuming this all happens inside an `async` function...

```js
async function limitToFiftyApiCalls(records) {
  const max = Math.min(records.length, 50);
  for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    const record = records[i];
    let brregRawData = await fetch(`some url/${record.name}/someurl`);
    let brregJson = await brregRawData.json();
    let personNavn = brregJson.rollegrupper[0].roller[0].person.navn.fornavn;
    let personEtternavn = brregJson.rollegrupper[0].roller[0].person.navn.etternavn;
    // if mellomnavn = undefined, then do nothing
    if (brregJson.rollegrupper[0].roller[0].person.navn.mellomnavn == undefined) {
      var personMellomNavn = "";
    } else {
      let personMellomNavn = brregJson.rollegrupper[0].roller[0].person.navn.mellomnavn + " ";
    }
  }
}
```

The code above doesn't modify your existing code much other than limiting the number of API calls. However there's a few things you could do that would generally make the code easier to read and edit.

```js
async function limitToFiftyApiCalls(records) {
  const max = Math.min(records.length, 50);
  for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    const record = records[i];
    let personMellomNavn = "";
    let brregRawData = await fetch(`some url/${record.name}/someurl`);
    let brregJson = await brregRawData.json();

    // why write this more than once?
    // save it to a variable and make life easier
    let someVar = brregJson.rollegrupper[0].roller[0].person.navn;
    
    let personNavn = someVar.fornavn;
    let personEtternavn = someVar.etternavn;
    if (someVar.mellomnavn) {
      personMellomNavn = someVar.mellomnavn + ' '
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Saving the path to a variable is gold, makes the code so much easier to read! Thank you for both providing a solution, explanation of the solution and even a tip on how to write easier to read code! I very much appreciate that you have spent time helping me with this!

Answer (score 0):

Answer to you question:

```
for (let i=0; i<math.min(records.length, 50); i++ ) {
  let record = records[i];
```

But what happens then with the records you have not checked? Will you wait 24h? I guess that's not what's expected, and instead will have to check 50 records every hour until you have checked them all (so 4 times for 200 records).

Comment: The for loop will be scheduled to run 50 records every 1 hour from 5am to 7am. Thank you for providing a solution!